# insert input with fixed length

Tags: mysql

How would you go about making an integer's length in a table equal a set number of characters, no more and no less. Is there a method for this?

i tried the CHECK syntax but that didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer(
mid CHAR(4) <-- How would i make the input here exactly 4 when using the INSERT statement.
company_name VARCHAR(20),
);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: remove the `=`: `mid CHAR(4)`

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, that wasn't how I was trying to do it.

Comment: Input greater than 4 characters will automatically be truncated. Values smaller than 4 characters will be filled with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you want your column to always be the same length. If that's the case check this code:

```
 SELECT RPAD(SUBSTR('this is a very long text' FROM 1 FOR 10), 10, '-'),
        RPAD(SUBSTR('short' FROM 1 FOR 10), 10, '-');
```

If your text is longer than 10 characters then it will be cropped. 
If your text is shorter than 10 characters then '-' will be added to the end of the string to make it 10 characters long.

In your case that would match something like:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_column) VALUES (RPAD(SUBSTR('your_text', FROM 1 TO 4), 4, '-')));
```

Though you can do this programmatically as well.

Anyways please let me know if this is what you're looking for.